# How to add if statement into datatables?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have datatables which is render image inside table but what I've done is just if there is image then render but if no image not yet have statement

**here's my datatables**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#pengumuman-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('pengumuman.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'rownum', name: 'rownum' },
            { data: 'gambar', render: function(data)
                { return '<img src="{{ asset("/images/pengumuman/") }}/'+data+'" atl img style="width:200px; height:150px"/>' }
            },
            { data: 'nama_pengumuman', name: 'nama_pengumuman' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

How do I add statement if no image in datatable like this in php

```
@if(isset($pegawai->foto) && !empty($pegawai->foto))
  <div align="center"> 
  <img src="{{ asset("/images/karyawan/$pegawai->foto") }}" alt="" img style="width:250px; height:260px">
  </div>
@else
  <div align="center"> 
  <img src="http://www.blogsaays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/no-user-profile-picture-whatsapp.jpg" alt="" img style="width:250px; height:260px">
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [columns.defaultContent](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) option to set default static content for a column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#pengumuman-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('pengumuman.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { 
              data: 'rownum', 
              name: 'rownum' 
            },
            { 
              data: 'gambar', 
              render: function(data) { 
                if(data) {
                  return '<img src="{{ asset("/images/pengumuman/") }}/'+data+'" atl img style="width:200px; height:150px"/>' 
                }
                else {
                  return '<img src="http://www.blogsaays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/no-user-profile-picture-whatsapp.jpg" alt="" img style="width:250px; height:260px">'
                }

              },
              defaultContent: '<img src="http://www.blogsaays.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/no-user-profile-picture-whatsapp.jpg" alt="" img style="width:250px; height:260px">'
            },
            { 
              data: 'nama_pengumuman', 
              name: 'nama_pengumuman' 
            },
            { 
              data: 'created_at', 
              name: 'created_at'
            },
            { 
              data: 'action', 
              name: 'action', 
              orderable: false, 
              searchable: false
            }
        ]
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: if you are getting image for each and every data, then it will not show? Are you getting any warnings?

Comment: I did not get any warning just like no `defaultContent:` there

Comment: what is the content of data in this line --> `'<img src="{{ asset("/images/pengumuman/") }}/'+data+'"`

Comment: it's images name from database

Comment: thank you very much @Prashant Pokhriyal this work like a charm!!